# about HMVC in codeigniter and cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, cakephp-2.0

i heard today from my friend about HMVC in codignitor..i surprise for this feature..it is very helping in the big projects .. and i am Sad because i cant found any article or anything tell me there are HMVC in cakephp..so i have two questions..
Anyone have idea for HMVC in cakephp?
Is these Brings me to learn codignitor ?
Do the plugins, such as HMVC?

**login example in codignitor HMVC**

```
<?php
hmvcExample/application/modules/login/controllers/  
hmvcExample/application/modules/login/models/  
hmvcExample/application/modules/login/views/ 
ci_day6/application/controllers/login.php  
ci_day6/application/models/membership_model.php  
ci_day6/application/views/login_form.php  
ci_day6/application/views/signup_form.php  
ci_day6/application/views/signup_successful.php  

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/890/Understanding-Model-View-Controller

HMVC is only a extension of MVC and is partly supported by using Plugins, elements etc.
In 2.1 there will even be View blocks available.

The whole concept of HMVC is questionable, though, imo. Cake's MVC basic principles work well enough.